# How to show/hide div on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, hide, mouseover, show

I'm trying to have one div show up when you mouse over.

I am using jQuery 1.3.

Here's what I have:

```
$('#hoveroverthis').hover(function() {$('#showbox').show()});
```

Shouldn't this work?

Edit: Fixed. Thanks everyone!

Comment: the js code is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9pNdm/ so please post a fiddle with a self contained example showing your attempts.

Comment: Would it matter if #hoveroverthis was inside of another div class maybe?

Comment: nope, it looks for an element with the ID you mentioned , it doesn't care who its `parent` is.

Comment: @Senkou, no, it doesn't matter since you're targeting an element by its id attribute.

Comment: Your question before edit contained two </script> tag.Was that a Typo?

Comment: @AnkitGautam There's one set for pulling the jquery.js file, then another set for this function, why?

Comment: Also, should I have "display:none;" in the CSS for the div thats supposed to show up?

Comment: @Senkou there was two consecutive </script> tag and one more </script> tag.See carefully

Comment: I see what you mean, fixed, but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitive answer to this question is: **yes**, that should work *assuming* that you've typed the correct element IDs and that the elements with those IDs exist at the time this script is run.

To make sure that the document is ready to be manipulated by JavaScript, wrap your code in a handle to the document 'ready' event. jQuery has a shortcut for this:

```
$(function() {
    // Everything in this context will be executed when the document is ready
    $('#hoveroverthis').hover(function() {$('#showbox').show()});
});
```

Comment: This script is contained within the <head> tags

Comment: @Senkou: Then that explains it. Since your script runs before the elements in your page has been created, nothing happens. Use the code in my answer instead and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this code in `$.document.ready()` function and check it

Comment: that will bind the events to the element after the DOM is loaded

Comment: @Senkou check it http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){//when document is ready (loaded) these functions will initialise
  $('#hoveroverthis').hover(function() {
     $('#showbox').show()
  },function() {//mouseleave event
     $('#showbox').hide()
  });  
});
```